# How to get all names whose value is true?

Tags: javascript

In javascript, let's say I have this:

```
var foo = { a: true, b: false, c: true };
```

How do I get all the names whose values are true? In the above case, this code would return `['a', 'c']`

Comment: Looks like the result should be `["a", "c"]`, not `['a', 'b']`...

Comment: @Denys yes, sorry. corrected

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is very simple:

```
let trues = Object.keys(foo).filter(n=>foo[n]);
```

If you want to be compatible with ES5 (which is a good idea today if your code runs untranspiled in a browser), use

```
var trues = Object.keys(foo).filter(function(n){ return foo[n] });
```